# Rails: Duplicate functionality across controllers? A humble plea

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm working with authlogic, and I'm trying to duplicate the login functionality to the welcome page, so that you can log in by restful url or by just going to the main page. No, I don't know if we'll keep that feature, but I want to test it out anyway. Here's the error message:

`RuntimeError in Welcome#index
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`

The code is below. Basically, what's happening is the index view (the first code snippet) is sending the information from the form to the create method of user_sessions controller. At this point, in theory, it create should just pick up, but it doesn't.

PLEASE help. Please. I've been doing this for about 8 hours. I checked Google. I checked IRC. I checked every book I could find. You don't even have to answer, I can to the grunt work if you just point me in the right direction.

## ===EDIT EDIT EDIT===

Sameera was good enough to provide the answer to the problem. Open question, though is what the best way to organize the app is. Is applying the object @user_sessions in a before_filter acceptable, or is there a more rails-y way of doing this?

WELCOME#INDEX

```
<% form_for @user_session, :url => user_sessions_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

APPLICATION CONTROLLER

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
  # Scrub sensitive parameters from your log
  # filter_parameter_logging :password
    helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
    before_filter :new_session_object
protected
    def new_session_object
        unless current_user
        @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    end
end
private
def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end
def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
end<pre></code>
```

USER SESSIONS CONTROLLER

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :controller => 'user_sessions', :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user_session = UserSession.find
    @user_session.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out"
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

A more detailed STACK TRACE

```
1: <h1>Welcome#index</h1>
2: <p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
3: 
4: <% form_for @user_session, :url => user_sessions_path do |f| %>
5:  <%= f.text_field :email %><br />
6:      <%= f.password_field :password %>
7:  <%= submit_tag 'Login' %>

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpac -2.3.5/lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:76:in `dom_id'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/record_identification_helper.rb:16:in `dom_id'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:293:in `apply_form_for_options!'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:277:in `form_for'
/Users/alex/Desktop/anglic/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb:4:in `_run_erb_app47views47welcome47index46html46erb'
```

Comment: Please post the code for Welcome#index. A more detailed stack trace might not be a bad idea either.

Comment: That was actually the first code snippet, but I can see how that would be unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
form_for :user_session, @user_session, :url => user_session_path(@user_session)} do |f| 

end
```

Comment: WOOO! IT WORKS! Sameera, sir (or ma'am!), you are an amazing and beautiful person. Please accept my most sincere and boisterous thanks. I give you rights to my firstborn. May all the gods in heaven shower you with money and fame.

Comment: Hi,

Nice to see you found my answer useful :D

cheers,
sameera

Comment: Hi Alex,
I got this example from  action view examples. (/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.2.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper
)

If possible try to use netbeans (I'm using 6.9) and it gives automatic  code completion and examples as you type

I think its a great IDE 

cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following method to the ApplicationController:

```
def require_user
    unless current_user
        flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page!"
        redirect_to :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "new"            
        return false
    end
end
```

Then in the WelcomeController add a before filter like this:

```
before_filter :require_user
```

Now, anybody accessing WelcomeController will be redirected to the login page. You don't have to duplicate the functionality across controllers.

Please go through the Authlogic set-up tutorial for details: http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic

Comment: Hi, Syed. Sorry, not to be difficult, but every ounce of work you cause users is another excuse for them to just leave the site completely. It's not that I don't know I can't before_filter the users, it's that I frankly don't want to.

Comment: Also, thanks for the site, but I have in fact scoured it. My authentication system, for example, is highly customized. Also, I would not dream of bothering the good folks of SO unless I felt I had exhausted all solutions at my disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this in your WelcomeController

```
class WelcomeController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    @user_session = UserSession.new
    .....
  end

  ..... 

end
```

It seems to me that you are trying to use @user_session which is not defined in the view of WelcomeController index action.

Hopefully it helps.

**EDIT #1**

It seems to me that the problem occur when the before_filter was called, after you submit the form in the WelcomeController#index action.

This particular section of code is strange to me

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  .....
  private
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end
  .....

end
```

I am quite sure `UserSession.find` will break.

Hopefully this edit helps.

**EDIT #2**

Another thing that I found strange is inside the protected method new_session_object:

```
protected
    def new_session_object
        unless current_user
        @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    end
end
```

Any reason why the `UserSession.new` was created with `params[:user_session]` ?

The flow for your `UserSessionController` login as far as I understand it is:

1. `before_filter`
   `:new_session_object` is called
2. it will return `false` for
   `current_user` since it is a new
   user session
3. it will set `@user_session` variable
   to
   `UserSession.new(params[:user_session])`
   value
4. `UserSessionController#new` action
   is called which override
   `@user_session` variable to
   `UserSession.new`
5. `new.html.erb` is rendered
   containing the form for login
6. `before_filter :new_session_object
   is` called again
7. it will return `false` for
   `current_user` since it is still a
   new user session
8. it will set `@user_session` variable
   to
   `UserSession.new(params[:user_session])`
   value
9. `UserSessionController#create`
   action is called which will again
   set the `@user_session` variable to
   `UserSession.new(params[:user_session])`
   value.
10. `@user_session` is saved and the
     user session is successfully
     created

**BUT for the `WelcomeController` it is subtly different in step 4**

The `@user_session` variable value that is used in the `WelcomeController#index` came from the `before_filter` call variable assignment of `UserSession.new(params[:user_session])`, at that point the `params[:user_session]` value is `nil`, so the `@user_session = UserSession.new(nil)` when the i`ndex.html.erb` was rendered.

I am not entirely sure if this is the thing that cause your problem, but it may help you to troubleshoot this issue if you run `script/server --debugger` and step trough the creation of `@user_session` when using `WelcomeController`, specially when the form is posted to `UserSessionController#create`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Two things. First, it isn't that the form doesn't load (the before_filter in the appcontroller makes that instance variable for us), it's that when we submit the order, @user_session should propagate from Welcome#index to UserSessions#create. Instead, we get the error above. And second, I'd hate to duplicate the code in the acutal UserSessionsController, which does exactly what your code indicates. Is there a way to make is so that I can just call UserSessionsController's version of new instead?

Thanks again for the response.

Comment: Thanks once again for the response! So my question then would be, why does it NOT break if I issue a POST :create from within the UserSessions controller? The only time I get this error is when I try to POST :create from a different controller. Also, that's an internal method that Authlogic needs to maintain sessions, and I think it gets run at least once every request. So I would expect the error to manifest more than it has, though I could be wrong about that.